# Create sql function that returns rows above certain input

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create an sql function that will return any row that have a certain coulmn value that is bigger or equal to the user input number.
I am using PL/SQL developer, oracle sql.

For example this is the table:

```
MyTable

id  name
5   Zack
4   David
3   Mike
```

So if the input of the user would be 4 he would recieve this table:

```
id  name
5   Zack
4   David
```

Comment: What should this function return? A cursor, an array, ... ? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want that the function will return a table if possible, I couldn't find any leads that I  could implemnt fo far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need table functions.
For example:

```
create table MyTable(id, name) as (
    select 5,   'Zack' from dual union
    select 4,   'David' from dual union
    select 3,   'Mike' from dual
);
/
CREATE TYPE t_record AS OBJECT (
  num           NUMBER,
  string        VARCHAR2(50)
);
/
CREATE TYPE t_table IS TABLE OF t_record;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_table (pN IN NUMBER) RETURN t_table AS
  vReturn  t_table;
BEGIN
  SELECT t_record(id, name)
  bulk collect into vReturn
  from myTable
  where id <= pN;

  RETURN vReturn;
END;
/
```

This

```
select *
from table(get_table(4))
```

gives:

```
       NUM STRING                                            
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         3 Mike                                              
         4 David
```

Comment: Small thing , I needed id >= pN, but that's the solution I was searching for, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,name from MyTable where id>=(select id from MyTable)/*imagining using subquery user can give input/*
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically need it to be a function with an interaction/input dialogue

Comment: then you need to use programming language and then connect the database using odbc or jdbc connection.

Comment: I specifically need to use the CREATE FUNCTION syntex, is there a way to that istead of using query ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
"SELECT * FROM MyTable where id>= "userInput;
```

Hope it helps.